# PHPMailer Laravel issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having an issue using PHPmailer class in laravel ,sometimes the email is sent and in very rare case its not sent but after the $mail->send() function all the other script is running fine and it doesn't even throw any error and I am unable to find out whats wrong. below is my code.

```
 $to_email = '';
        $from_email = 'banca@jubileegeneral.com.pk';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try {
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl'  => array(
                       'verify_peer' => false,
                       'verify_peer_name' => false,
                       'allow_self_signed' => true
                               )
            );
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                      // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.something.com.pk';                    // Set the SMTP server 
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = 'something@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = 'xyz';                               // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;  
            $mail->Port       = 25;                                     // TCP port to connect to
            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom($from_email, 'TESTING');
            $mail->addAddress(Auth::user()->email);
            $mail->addBCC('something@abc.com.pk');
            $mail->isHTML(true);     
            $mail->Subject = 'XYZ ';
            $mail->Body    = 'Hey';
            $mail->AltBody = '';
            $mail->send();
```

Comment: If sometimes mails can be sent, but sometimes it fails, then I suggest you checking whether the recipients are having a very strong , restrictive spam policy for the cases of outgoing mail failures.

Comment: It's not surprising that you can't see anything going wrong because you have no error handling, you're not checking any return values, and your debug level is not high enough to show you what the server is saying. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, but also look at *any* of the examples provided with PHPMailer for how to handle error messages, enable exceptions, etc.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using PHPMailer instead of the built in [Mail functions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail)?